# (Angular 2/4/5/6) Get error response from server after subscribing to service

Tags: angular, angular6, subscribe

I'm trying to verify my otp. Based on the error response returned by the server (either otp mismatch or otp expired), I would like to display the error message accordingly. However, I'm not sure how to retrieve the error response from the server

[image]

Currently my console.log is getting a string from my otpService saying "Http failure response for http://xxx/verify: 400 Bad Request", so how do I retrieve the {"Err":"otp expired"} instead?

**otp.component.ts**

```
this.otpService
      .verify(id, this.paymentForm.controls.otp.value)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.router.navigate(["success"]);
        },
        // if otp has error, show error message
        error => {
          console.log(error); //this only gives me 400 Bad Request
        },
      );
```

**otp.service.ts**

```
verify(id: string, token: string): Observable<{}> {
const req = { id: id, otp: otp};
return this.http
  .put<{}>(appConfig.apiBasePath + "verify", req, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set(
      "Content-Type",
      "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    ),
  })
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError),
  );
```

}

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private errorList: string = '';    

public handleError(error) {
        if (error.error) {
          if (error.error instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < error.error.length; i++) {
              if (i === 0) {
                this.errorList = error.error[i].description;
              }
              else {
                this.errorList += " " + error.error[i].description;
              }
            }
            return Observable.throw(this.errorList);
          }
          else {
            return Observable.throw(error.error);
          }
        }
        else {
          return Observable.throw(error.message);
        }
      }
```

Just use this method to return your error from service